# Growing Strawberry Tree from Fruit

Tags: fruit-trees, planting, germination, seed-saving

I am very heartbroken to have had to have my beautiful mature Strawberry Tree taken out. I could not afford to have it transplanted, but I want to preserve it in some way. I did not think to ask for cuttings, but I still have some ripe fruit. Is it possible to grow a strawberry tree from the fruit?

Comment: What do mean by a strawberry tree? What species?

Comment: You are presumably referring to Arbutus of some variety?

Answer (score 3):

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arbutus_unedo) says this about sprouting them from seed:

"Propagation can be done via seed, layering, or cutting.

The seed should undergo a one month cold stratification period, then soaked for 5 to 6 days in warm water to improve germination success. Seedlings are prone to damp, and should be cared in the first year.

Germination rate is low, rarely over 20%."